# QGIS - Intersect Spatial GRID and Polygons - Return whole cells on the boundary

Tags: qgis, intersection

I've been managing within QGIS two shapefiles: the first is a spatial square grid, and the second a city region. Now I would like to intersect the grid keeping only the cells that are overlapping the city, returning the whole cells on the boundaries. So far I used the Intersect function which returns this:

[image]

Is there a way (within QGIS or Python, for instance) to keep the whole cells overlapping the boundaries of the blue region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this spatial queries plugin. It should allow you do what you are looking for. [Spatial Queries Plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html)